# UITextField RightView crash app when using 2 or more

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't know if this is a bug or what but I can't understand why it happens.
I have 2 `UITextField` that once clicked show the users an `UIPickerView`, everything was working fine until I tried to add a custom arrow image in order to let the user know about the dropdown. this is the code I've used in order to create the rightView:

```
    UIImageView *arrowDown = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"p-dropdown"]];
    arrowDown.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 22);
    _province.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    _province.rightView = arrowDown;
    _address.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    _address.rightView = arrowDown;
```

As soon as the last line ends the app freezes and it starts using like 20MB/s of RAM without stopping, I tried to comment all the code above and the problem doesn't occur, the funny thing is that if I comment just one of the two rightView ,so something like this:

```
UIImageView *arrowDown = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"p-dropdown"]];
arrowDown.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 22);
_province.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_province.rightView = arrowDown;
```

I can correctly see the rightView and the app doesn't freeze. Can someone help me to understand what is causing this weird issue?

Comment: Could you just test one thing? Make a new instance of ArrowDown like arrowdown1 and assign that to address textfield right view. I once had an issue with that (Though not crash). This fixed it.

Comment: What I inferred from it was that One UIView instance cant be utilized as right view of multiple textfields.  But I didn't look it up to get more credible reference.

Comment: @NSNoob yeah that's the problem, on another answer I just found out that: A single UIView (or UIImageView) cannot be displayed on screen twice at the same time. If you want to post it as answer i'll accept as soon as I can, ty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One instance of `UIView` can't be utilized as right view of multiple `UITextFields`. You have to make two instances of your `UIImageView` to make your app work as expected. As you yourself found out, that one view cant be displayed on a screen multiple times simultaneously.